# How to properly Export JavaFX Project

Tags: java, export

I have created a JavaFX project in Eclipse and I want to export it so I can actually use the program.

How I installed the libraries:
I went to preferences, Java, Installed JRE's, click on the java version I am using and hit add external jars. I add all of the jars from the JavaFX lib folder and then in the default VM args I have

--module-path /Users/bennybergle/Documents/JavaFX/javafx-sdk-15/lib --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml

Now, when I export it, I right click on the project, click export, Runnable JAR file and then I select the Radio Button that says Package all required libraries into generated jar, and then finish.

The problem is that I can't actually open the exported jar file. It doesn't give me an error message or anything, nothing happens on MacOS or Windows. Can someone please explain how to properly export the jar file so it will run?

Comment: Try running the jar file from the command line, and it should print out errors to the console to help diagnose the problem `java -jar yourFile.jar`

Comment: thanks for that! When I ran it in terminal it gave me a NoClassDefFoundError: javafx/application/Application. I'll look more into that error.